# How to import a JSON file into postgresql databse?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I just tried to read a .JSON file in my PostgreSQL database but it is not able to read it. I did it with a .csv file, but with a .JSON file, I am not able to do it.

This is how the .JSON file looks like:

```
{"s":"S1","p":"P1","j":"J1","qty":200}
{"s":"S1","p":"P1","j":"J4","qty":700}
{"s":"S2","p":"P3","j":"J1","qty":400}
{"s":"S2","p":"P3","j":"J2","qty":200}
```

This is the code that I tried, I created the table first and then copy the data from the file into the database.

```
create table notifies(
    s varchar(999),
    p varchar(999),
    j varchar(999),
    qty varchar(999)
);

copy public.notifies(s,p,j,qty)
from 'C:\temp\spj.json';
```

Comment: COPY can't "read" json, just INSERT a single row into a single column.

Comment: So, How could I insert a column from a .json file?

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer. See [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html). As example: `select * from json_to_record('{"s":"S1","p":"P1","j":"J1","qty":200}') as t(s varchar, p varchar, j varchar, qty integer);                                                                                                      s  | p  | j  | qty 
----+----+----+-----
 S1 | P1 | J1 | 200`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import this json file of yours to a temporary table and from there populate the table `notifies`. For example:

Create a tmp table ..

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (c text);
```

.. import your json file into the table `tmp` using `COPY`  ..

```
mydb=# \copy tmp from 'C:\temp\spj.json'
```

... and finally populate the table `notifies`:

```
INSERT INTO notifies 
SELECT q.* FROM tmp, json_to_record(c::json) AS q
 (s text, p text, j text, qty int);

SELECT * FROM notifies;

 s  | p  | j  | qty 
----+----+----+-----
 S1 | P1 | J1 | 200
 S1 | P1 | J4 | 700
 S2 | P3 | J1 | 400
 S2 | P3 | J2 | 200
(4 Zeilen)
```

After that you may want to drop the table `tmp`

```
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

**EDIT**: A quite elegant alternative is to use `json_populate_record`, as suggested by @Jeremy. Thanks! See comments below.

```
INSERT INTO notifies 
SELECT q.* FROM tmp, json_populate_record(null::notifies, c::json) AS q;

SELECT * FROM notifies ;
 s  | p  | j  | qty 
----+----+----+-----
 S1 | P1 | J1 | 200
 S1 | P1 | J4 | 700
 S2 | P3 | J1 | 400
 S2 | P3 | J2 | 200
(4 Zeilen)
```

Comment: Note that instead of `json_to_record(c::json) AS q
 (s text, p text, j text, qty int)`, you could use `json_populate_record(null::notifies, c::json)`.  It's easier to reuse the notifies type.

Answer (score 0):

One way to this is to use sling. See this [blog post](https://blog.slingdata.io/import-local-json-files-into-postgresql) which covers loading JSON files into PG.

```bash
# in Windows Powershell
$ set POSTGRES 'postgresql://...'

$ sling conns list
+------------+------------------+-----------------+
| CONN NAME  | CONN TYPE        | SOURCE          |
+------------+------------------+-----------------+
| POSTGRES   | DB - PostgreSQL  | env variable    |
+------------+------------------+-----------------+

$ sling run --src-stream file://C:/temp/records.json --tgt-conn POSTGRES --tgt-object public.records --mode full-refresh
11:09AM INF connecting to target database (postgres)
11:09AM INF reading from source file system (file)
11:09AM INF writing to target database [mode: full-refresh]
11:09AM INF streaming data
11:09AM INF dropped table public.records
11:09AM INF created table public.records
11:09AM INF inserted 500 rows in 0 secs [1,556 r/s]
11:09AM INF execution succeeded
```

Using `debug` mode would show a DDL of `create table if not exists public.records ("data" jsonb)`. If you would like to flatten your JSON, sling does that as well by adding the `--src-options 'flatten: true'` option:

```bash
$ sling run --src-stream file://C:/temp/records.json --src-options 'flatten: true' --tgt-conn POSTGRES --tgt-object public.records --mode full-refresh
```

The DDL in that case would be something like:

```sql
create table if not exists public.records ("_id" varchar(255),
"age" integer,
"balance" varchar(255),
"company__about" text,
"company__address" varchar(255),
"company__email" varchar(255),
"company__latitude" numeric,
"company__longitude" numeric,
"company__name" varchar(255),
"company__phone" varchar(255),
"company__registered" varchar(255),
"isactive" bool,
"name" varchar(255),
"picture" varchar(255),
"tags" jsonb)
```

FYI, I am the author of sling.